# python library for visualizing AWS Neptune with SPARQL

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I am looking for a python tool that can help me build a visualization dashboard for my AWS Neptune RDF graph database using the SPARQL query language, something that looks similar to Reactome: https://reactome.org/PathwayBrowser/

My goal is to allow users to allow for interactive data exploration of the graph database visually rather than having to write their own SPARQL queries. I've seen tools for neo4j, but i have a lot of experience with SPARQL and would prefer that.

Are there any popular libraries or tools that can help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a tool that already integrates SPARQL querying and rendering the visualizations or are you able/willing to write some code to glue the pieces together? There are a lot of nice open source visualization libraries that can be used from Python

Comment: Yeah I am fine to write code, I just wasnt sure if something like Plotly or matplotlib is used for graph databases.

Comment: You can certainly use those but they are probably not the best choice for building something interactive. I have used libraries such as PyVis which sits on top of Vis.js (so ultimately runs as an HTML canvas but can be configured in Python). A lot of the libraries tend to be JavaScript/CSS based, but you can wrap them in Python if need be. There are also the Neptune notebooks (graph-notebook project) but those are more aimed at people writing queries.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to check out pyvis. Thanks!